# Django Nested Serializer - Return Null Field if condition is fullfiled

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a nested serializes, which content I need to return as Null in case of the parent-serializer field "is_profile_private" (a boolean) is True.
I tried using get_queryset in order to filter the User Profile but no progress was made.
Tried using SerializerMethordField() and get_profile() but Django complained about UserProfileSerializer type of object not being allowed to be serialized.

serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(UserSerializer):
    height = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "bio",
            "gender",
            "custom_gender",
            "non_binary_list",
            "birthdate",
            "avatar",
            "height",
            "hometown",
            "zodiac_sign",
            "language",
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_height(obj):
        return {"value": obj.height, "unit": obj.height_unit}


class SimpleUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(source="user", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "username",
            "is_profile_private",
            "date_joined",
            "profile",
        )
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileAPIView(RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    lookup_field = "id"
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SimpleUserSerializer
    http_method_names = ["get"]

    @staticmethod
    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        return User.objects.get(id=str(request.data))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class SimpleUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "username",
            "is_profile_private",
            "date_joined",
            "profile",
        )

    def get_profile(self, obj):
        if obj.is_profile_private:
            return None
        return UserProfileSerializer(obj.user).data
```

please note that you should return serializer's data, not serializere itself.

Comment: UserProfileSerializer(obj.user).data the obj.user was the thing I missed when trying the SerializerMethodField. Thank you

Comment: Can I do this without using SerializerMethodField? I need to perform patch/update so I'm using Custom Fields